# Python - Extract Values from List of Dictionary (generated by SQL command)

Tags: python, mysql, list, dictionary

Good Morning,

I'm trying to working with a MySQL DB in Python and I need to extract some data like table names.

So I run this code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host='myHost', user='user', password='password', db='test', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
a = conn.cursor()

sql="SHOW tables like '%s%'"
a.execute(sql)
rows = a.fetchall()
tables = []
for row in rows:
    tables.append(row.values())
```

but when I run `print(tables)` it give me a result like:

```
 ["dict_values(['table1'])", "dict_values(['table2'])"]
```

The only list that I need is `['table1', 'table2', 'etc', 'etc']`.
How can I solve this? It's the SQL statement that cause these kind of problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row.values()` returns a dict_values object, which acts like a list.

Since you can assume that there's only one value in that list, you can replace this line:

```
tables.append(row.values())
```

With this:

```
tables += row.values()
```

And you should get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this code the only thing ou have to keep in mind is this `tables.append(row.values()[0])` syntax cause you using the values of dictionary

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host='myHost', user='user', password='password', db='test', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
a = conn.cursor()
sql="SHOW tables"
a.execute(sql)
tables = []
rows = a.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    tables.append(list(row.values())[0])
```

Comment: It return: TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Comment: In python 3 row.values() returns view instead of list so you can change the last line to this tables.append(list(row.values())[0]) @andrepogg